# Cognito Facebook social login with Angular 6: How to use returned code to authenticate user in amplify Auth

Tags: angular, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I have an angular 6 app and am trying to configure social signin (facebook) with amplify from the docs.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-pools-social-idp.html

I implemented the steps required and then generated the url to trigger hosted login.

`https://<your_user_pool_domain>/login?response_type=code&client_id=<your_client_id>&redirect_uri=https://www.example.com`

This redirected me to facebook and then redirected back to my site as expected with the code in the url.

`https://<mysite>/browse?code=1bfabc0e-f4cd-4889-8811-eaaa71rf6e35#_=_`

I can't find any documentation on how I exchange that code for JWT using the amplify library.

https://aws-amplify.github.io/amplify-js/media/angular_guide

I've implemented basic cognito login using the Authenticaor

`<amplify-authenticator></amplify-authenticator>`

And when the password and username are submitted I can see in the http response the accessToken and idToken being returned.

```
Auth.signIn(username, password)
.then(user => console.log(user))
.catch(err => console.log(err));
```

I have tried looking through AmplifyService and Auth methods but can't find anything which allows me to submit a code instead of username and password.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I know I am a bit late, but you this is documented here:  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-pools-app-idp-settings.html under Allowed OAuth Flows

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use https://github.com/zyra/ngx-facebook to obtain `accessToken` instead of `code`.
2. You can send `accessToken` to API to change it to long-lived (60 days) token:

> ```
> public function grantFacebookAccess(Request $request Facebook $fb) {
>     $accessToken =  $request->get('accessToken');
>     $oAuth2Client = $fb->getOAuth2Client();
>     $longLivedAccessToken = $oAuth2Client->getLongLivedAccessToken($accessToken);
>     $params = "first_name,last_name,age_range,gender";
>     $user = $fb->get('/me?fields='.$params, $longLivedAccessToken)->getGraphUser();
>     print_r($user);
> }
> ```

Facebook class is from `facebook/graph-sdk` (check this: https://quantizd.com/facebook-php-sdk-with-laravel/)